# GWT - fancy Google-style buttons?

Tags: java, css, gwt, button

I'm curious, is there a way to style buttons in my GWT application to make them look the same way they do in GMail?

[image]

Are these "buttons" at all? What's the easiest way to get the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're just divs with fancy styles! Check them out with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)!

Comment: Still, if someone has turned these into GWT widgets it would save me some time. Anybody?

Answer (score 2):

The current version are divs styles with CSS3 properties like `gradient` and `border-radius`. Prior to this version GMail had a button also created by divs but not using CSS3 styles. The button was much more complex (several nested divs). That latter button is available for GWT in the library cobogw:
See [demo](http://cobogw.googlecode.com/svn/demo/WidgetsDemo.html#Button) and [cobogw on google code](http://cobogw.googlecode.com).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Theme called clean. Check it out: